# Webpage can not access jar for applet

Tags: maven, servlets, applet

I created two maven project: `project-applet` and `project-webapp`.

The java applet works fine: I can start it with the `applet-viewer` in a static html file with the necessary applet-tag.

Now I'm trying to move this static html file into a servlet (actually just it's content) `index.jsp`

```
<html>
<body>
    <applet
        code="project.applet.Applet.class"
        codebase="/lib"
        archive="project-applet-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar" width="900"
        height="300"> Your browser is completely ignoring the applet tag! </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm building everything with maven. The `project-applet-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar` is in the `project-webapp-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war` file in this position `WEB-INF/lib/`.

I also tried to just copy it to `project-webapp/src/main/webapp/` with `codebase="/"` but this didn't help even if the jar can be download from `localhost:8080/project-webapp/project-applet-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your servlet mapped with a `/` *after* it in the url-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jar is lying at `localhost:8080/project-webapp/project-applet-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`, the codebase is like this `codebase="/project-webapp/"`